# Real URL for the Vivvo cms

Tags: url, url-rewriting

I would like to know what is the real url for vivvo cms without url rewriting. SEO friendly url is something like that: www.siteurl.com/anyfolder/234234.html
and I want to know that is the real url for that. for example: www.siteurl.com/show_news.php?newsid=234234

first of all is it possible?

thanks in advance,
Ali

Comment: I got it. www.siteurl.com/article/articleidnumber is very fine and that works for me. Thanks a lot!

on this site: http://www.vivvo.net/forums/showpost.php?p=20120&postcount=2

this code part gave me the solution:

$title = preg_replace('/&[a-zA-Z0-9#]{2,7};/', '', $article->title);

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. www.siteurl.com/article/articleidnumber is very fine and that works for me. Thanks a lot!

on this site: http://www.vivvo.net/forums/showpost.php?p=20120&postcount=2

this code part gave me the solution:

$title = preg_replace('/&[a-zA-Z0-9#]{2,7};/', '', $article->title);

Thanks again!